# Direct3D Error Code 80070057

Tags: directx9

I'm getting a failure returned when calling Direct3DDevice->CreateDepthStencilSurface(). But rather than returning one of the values that the documentation says it should return (D3DERR_NOTAVAILABLE, D3DERR_INVALIDCALL, D3DERR_OUTOFVIDEOMEMORY, E_OUTOFMEMORY), it returns error code 80070057. What does this mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the DirectX Error Lookup tool that's found in the SDK.

Passing this value in it returns the following result:

HRESULT: 0x80070057 (2147942487)
Name: E_INVALIDARG
Description: An invalid parameter was passed to the returning function
Severity code: Failed
Facility Code: FACILITY_WIN32 (7)
Error Code: 0x0057 (87)

You have an invalid argument passed into the function. Check the contents of your parameters.

Comment: You may also find it useful to enable the Debug runtimes (via the DirectX control panel, which is accessible under the DX SDK's Start Menu entry). This will print some additional useful diagnostic information to the output window at runtime which can sometimes help clarify DX's otherwise-very-general error messages.